# How to make your own 3D printer?

Tags: printer-building, reprap

I am wondering if I can get some electronic and mechanical layout of the machine.

Is it possible to make 3D printer components with 3D printer?

Comment: -1 as your question is too broad in its current state. Please show that you have at least done some research that can narrow your focus.

Comment: Look at the RepRap Project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, look at http://reprap.org for a project that's been doing what you're asking about for about a decade now.